# Target class [App\Http\Controller\ContactController] does not exist. Laravel 9

Tags: laravel

i am beginner of laravel. i ran into the problem .**Target class [App\Http\Controller\ContactController] does not exist.**
i set the all the routes files currectly.i don't why this errors is displaying.

**ContactController**

```
 public function index()
    {
        $contacts = Contact::all();
        return view('contact.index')->with('contacts',$contacts);
    }
```

View Page

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')

<div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">About</div>
        <div class="card-body">  

            @foreach($contacts as $contact)
            <p>{{ $contact->name }}</p>
            <p>{{ $contact->address }}</p>
            <p>{{ $contact->mobile }}</p> 
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>



@stop
```

i attached the screen shot image below.
[image]

**Routes**

```
use App\Http\Controller\ContactController;

    Route::resource('/contact',ContactController::class);
```

Comment: you missed an `s`, the `use` statement for the `ContactController` should be `use App\Http\Controllers\ContactController;`. Anyway, that depends also on the `namespace` you wrote on the `ContactController` file itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controllers live in `App\Http\Controllers`, so edit

```
use App\Http\Controller\ContactController;
```

to

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ContactController;
```

make sure the file namespace is correct too